# Java method called from R using .jcall is not refreshing when java method is updated

Tags: r, rjava

I am trying to call a specific java method from R like this,

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
.jaddClassPath("E:\\JAVA learn\\check\\bin") # path to class file
.jclassPath()
obj1 <- .jnew("check") #to create an object
result <- .jcall(obj1, "I", "try")
result
```

The try method in my check class is like this

```
public int try()
{
    return 30;
}
```

But when I update the try method to return **50** and redo the above steps the value of the result is still 30 only and it is not getting updated.

If I close R and open again and run it, its updating result to 50. I want it to update the result value without restarting R. Please Help!